# C++ function parameter that extends multiple classes

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

I have the following design problem, some manager class has a function that is supposed to allow classes that extend a specific set of classes and add them to a container that keeps the functionality of that specific set of classes. So we have:

```
class Base_1 {};
class Base_2 {};

class A :
    public Base_1,
    public Base_2
{

};

class Container 
{
    template<typename T> // where T should extend Base_1 and Base_2
    void Add(T* pObj) {
        elements.push_back(pObj);
    }

    std::vector<???> elements; // all elements should extend Base_1 and Base_2
};
```

Something similar is possible in C# with interfaces but I cant find any way to solve this in c++.

I do not want to create an intermediate class Base_1_2 because that stops working with 3 base classes where some manager needs its elements to have base classes 1 and 2, and another manager needs 2 and 3.

So my question is, how do u design this?

---

EDIT:
In response to:
"This smells like an XY problem" – cdhowie

I can imagine that's the case. So I'll try to explain the 'X' problem.

I have a set of classes that share a lot of functionality. Something like "load to gpu" "render" "release gpu memory" "update". But not all functionality is applicable to all classes. Some might not have the "render" for example. Now i have a class that needs to store a lot of objects and check if "load to gpu" has happened yet before calling "render". But how to implement this? How can u store classes based on this combination of functionality (I might be going towards the 'Y' a bit here again).

---

Edit 2:

Similar (but not generic) to the alternative composed by cdhowie, the following would be a solution too? (maybe leaving out the is_base_of on the Add function)

```
class MyWrapper
{
public:

    template<class T, typename = std::enable_if_t<
        std::is_base_of<Base_1, T>::value && std::is_base_of<Base_2, T>::value>>
        static MyWrapper MakeWrapper(T* pObj)
    {
        return MyWrapper(dynamic_cast<Base_1*>(pObj), dynamic_cast<Base_2*>(pObj));
    }

    Base_1* as_base_1;
    Base_2* as_base_2;

private:

    MyWrapper(Base_1* p1, Base_2* p2) {
        as_base_1 = p1;
        as_base_2 = p2;
    }
};


class Container
{
public:

    template<class T>
    void Add(T* pObj) {
        elements.push_back(MyWrapper::MakeWrapper<T>(pObj));
    }

    void Update() {
        for (auto& e : elements) {
            e.as_base_1->do_1();
            e.as_base_2->do_2();
        }
    }

    std::vector<MyWrapper> elements; // all elements should extend Base_1 and Base_2
};


void test() {
    A* pA = nullptr;
    Container c;
    c.Add(pA);
}
```

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/218910).

Comment: What is the definition of your class that extends Base_1 and Base_2?

Comment: Based on your additional explanation, there is possible solution whose implementation is ugly but whose usage is elegant -- you have a wrapper type that ensures that the wrapped object inherits from all of the types you need, and *that* is what you store in the vector.

Comment: The alternative in your answer is basically a less flexible version of the one in my answer. You would have to maintain different versions for each set of interfaces. One advantage of mine is that the set of interfaces is specified directly in the template arguments, so you don't have to author a new wrapper class for each set -- just use a new instantiation of the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable `Add` when `T` isn't derived from both types:

```
template<typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_base_of<Base_1, T>::value &&
    std::is_base_of<Base_2, T>::value,
    void
>::type Add(T* pObj) {
    elements.push_back(pObj);
}
```

Then the type of pointer you store in the vector doesn't make much difference, *if* `Base_1` and `Base_2` are polymorphic (just add a virtual destructor to both) -- then you can `dynamic_cast` to whatever type you need.  So you could store `Base_1 *` or `Base_2 *`.

You could also have two vectors: one to store `Base_1` pointers and one to store `Base_2` pointers, and this wouldn't require either type to be polymorphic.

However, this seems like a particularly strange problem to solve and you might consider taking a step back from your design to see if there is a better alternative solution.

---

> I do not want to create an intermediate class Base_1_2 because that stops working with 3 base classes where some manager needs its elements to have base classes 1 and 2, and another manager needs 2 and 3.

This is untrue.  Just use virtual inheritance in the intermediate classes.

---

As an alternative, you can write a type that will store pointers to all of the interfaces you require.  For example:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <tuple>

template <typename, typename...>
struct is_subtype_of_all : std::true_type {};

template <typename Derived, typename Base, typename... BaseTail>
struct is_subtype_of_all<Derived, Base, BaseTail...> : std::conditional<
    std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>::value,
    is_subtype_of_all<Derived, BaseTail...>,
    std::false_type
>::type {};

template <typename...>
struct type_index;

template <typename T, typename... Tail>
struct type_index<T, T, Tail...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 0> {};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Tail>
struct type_index<T, U, Tail...> : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, 1 + type_index<T, Tail...>::value> {};

template <typename... T>
class interface_wrapper
{
public:
    template <typename U, typename = typename std::enable_if<is_subtype_of_all<U, T...>::value>::type>
    explicit interface_wrapper(U *p)
        : pointers{static_cast<T *>(p)...} {}

    template <typename U>
    U * get() const
    {
        return std::get<type_index<U, T...>::value>(pointers);
    }

private:
    std::tuple<T *...> pointers;
};
```

Now, you can store `interface_wrapper<Base_1, Base_2>` in your vector, and you can use `.get<Base_1>()->some_member_of_Base_1` on the wrapper objects.

This implementation does not require that the object be polymorphic.

Comment: I want to use IContainer with function "Add" that checks if the object has the proper basetypes and then calls virtual function "AddImpl" with one of the base classes. So i need create a wrapper based on one of the base classes. How can i do that?

Comment: If you're using my code, just specify one template parameter. It can take as many template parameters as you need, and it will enforce that the type of the pointer passed to the constructor derives from all of the types in the class template arguments.

Comment: Yes the static enforcement is the problem.
If i need to extend all of B1, B2, B3.
The IContainer checks that 'x' extends B1 B2 B3 and then calls AddImpl(B1*) (which is a virtual function and thus cannot keep the type of 'x'). But then the wrapper expects something that extends B2 and B3 aswell, and i only have a pointer to B1*, even though i know it also extends B2 and B3 by design (not statically enforced).

Comment: Have AddImpl take the wrapper object directly. Store wrapper objects in your vectors, and you won't have to cast anything.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need the `std::enable_if` and `is_subtype_of_all` actually... the constructor will fail to instantiate anyway if `static_cast<T *>(p)...` is not well-formed.